# Problem with converting image to byte array

Tags: c#, arrays

For school we have to do a project in stenography, I have chosen to use a bmp and put text into it.  It works fine with normal pictures but from the moment on when you have pictures with a same byte sequence for example a white area or the image where I had the problem is [this picture](http://www.google.be/imgres?imgurl=http://www.animatoons.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2009/02/homer.bmp&imgrefurl=http://www.animatoons.com.br/os-simpsons/os-simpsons-vai-se-tornar-a-serie-mais-longa-da-historia/&usg=__mPrZZQsYK57Lc40HHwv8QOigh0M=&h=577&w=478&sz=272&hl=nl&start=0&zoom=1&tbnid=BH-3Jv2Hio_FUM%3a&tbnh=137&tbnw=113&ei=tgaLTcmTGsyWOvXl2M0N&prev=/images%3Fq%3Dhomer.bmp%26um%3D1%26hl%3Dnl%26sa%3DN%26biw%3D1440%26bih%3D720%26tbs%3Disch:1&um=1&itbs=1&iact=rc&dur=294&oei=tgaLTcmTGsyWOvXl2M0N&page=1&ndsp=30&ved=1t:429,r:18,s:0&tx=92&ty=82).

When I make from the bytearray where the text is in an image and I read it back the bytearray has changed. while the only thing I did was making an image from the bytearray and from the image back a bytearray.

This is my code:

```
namespace steganografie
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        dialog.Filter = "bmp files (*.bmp)|*.bmp|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        dialog.Title = "Select a image";
        dialog.InitialDirectory = Application.ExecutablePath;

        if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            txtText.Enabled = true;
            txtFile.Text = dialog.FileName;
            byte[] arImage = imageToByteArray(Image.FromFile(txtFile.Text));
            txtText.MaxLength = ((arImage.Length -54) /8)-5;
            lblCharLeft.Text = txtText.MaxLength+"";
            lblCharLeft.Tag = txtText.MaxLength;
            picOriginal.Image = Image.FromFile(dialog.FileName);
        }
    }
    private void btnSteganografie_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        byte[] arImage = imageToByteArray(Image.FromFile(txtFile.Text));
        string input = txtText.Text;
        string inputInBits = GetBits(input);
        char[] bits = inputInBits.ToCharArray();
        int i = 0;
        for (i = 54; (i < arImage.Length & i < bits.Length+54); i++)
        {
            if ((int)arImage[i] == 0)
            {
                arImage[i] = (byte)2;
            }
            if ((int)arImage[i] == 255)
            {
                byte bBit = new byte();
                bBit = 2;
                arImage[i] = (byte)(arImage[i]-bBit);
            }
            int lastBit = ((int)arImage[i]) % 2;
            int dataBit = ((int)bits[i - 54])%2;
            if (lastBit != dataBit)
            {
                arImage[i]++;
            }
        }
        arImage[i] = 0;
        Image result = byteArrayToImage(arImage);
        picEncoded.Image = result;
        SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
        if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            result.Save(sfd.FileName+".bmp",System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
        }
    }
    public string GetBits(string input)
    {
        StringBuilder sbBuilder = new StringBuilder();
         byte[] bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(input);
        foreach (byte bByte in Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(input))
        {
            int iByte = (int)bByte;

            for (int i = 7; i >= 0 & (iByte!=0 | i!=7); i--)
            {
                if (iByte - Math.Pow(2, i) >= 0)
                {
                    sbBuilder.Append("1");
                    iByte -= (int)Math.Pow(2, i);
                }
                else
                {
                    sbBuilder.Append("0");
                }
            }
        }
        return sbBuilder.ToString();
    }
    public byte[] imageToByteArray(System.Drawing.Image imageIn)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        imageIn.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
    public Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
    {
        //**********ERROR HAPPENS HERE *************
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
        Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
        byte[] arImageTEST = imageToByteArray(returnImage);
        //**********byteArrayIn should be the same as arImageTEST ***********
        return returnImage;
    }
 }
```

Comment: It might be difficult to hide information in an image with such obviously solid colors.

Comment: What kind of error? Is it an exception? Does it nothing?

Comment: Converting random bytes to UTF usually creates corruption. You'll never retrieve the correct bytes from that string.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it has something to do with this information available [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/93z9ee4x.aspx):

> You must keep the stream open for the
>   lifetime of the Image.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I think what they mean is that when you use the same stream again it will close the connection but i only use one time the stream so it should be stayed open,  I don't think that is the problem

Comment: I think that they mean that the information of the image is not duplicated and that the Image draws itself from the stream data. If you close the stream the memory gets freed and the Image data is not longer valid.

Comment: In this specific situation you can create the image and it's memory stream as class variables, in that way you will be able to have both of them live together.